# How to disable Blob existence check in Azure function Output Binding

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage, azure-log-analytics, azure-java-sdk

I have Azure function annotations defined as below. Blob trigger reads data from Storage account processes and uses return value to write Output to a Blob container with "filename".json defined in the binding.

This is working as expected; however, when writing the data to a blob container. Output binding is checking for the existence of Blob with "GET" request and ultimately getting into 404 response code before making a "PUT" request. This was captured in Application Insights.

Is there any way I can override this behavior?
[Screen shot of Log analytics here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XQQfy.png)

**FUNCTION BINDINGS**

```java
public class ProcessZipFiles2Cosmos {
    
    @FunctionName("ProcessZipFiles2Cosmos")
    @StorageAccount("blobStorageAccount")
    @BlobOutput(name = "blob_redacted_json", path = "nonpii/{filename}.json")
    public static String run(
        @BlobTrigger(name = "files", dataType = "binary", path = "transactedreturn/{name}", connection = "blobStorageAccount") byte[] content,
        @BindingName("name") String filename,
        @CosmosDBOutput(name = "cosmos_transacted", databaseName = "tax-return-data-ops", collectionName = "TransactedReturns", 
                        connectionStringSetting = "AzureCosmosDBConnection") OutputBinding<String> cosmosItem,
        final ExecutionContext context) {
        
        // function body
    }
}
```

**FUNCTION.JSON**

```json
{
   "scriptFile":"../transactedreturn-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar",
   "entryPoint":"com.hrblock.clzconverter.ProcessZipFiles2Cosmos.run",
   "bindings":[
      {
         "type":"blobTrigger",
         "direction":"in",
         "name":"files",
         "path":"transactedreturn/{name}",
         "dataType":"binary",
         "connection":"blobStorageAccount"
      },
      {
         "type":"cosmosDB",
         "direction":"out",
         "name":"cosmos_transacted",
         "databaseName":"tax-return-data-ops",
         "connectionStringSetting":"AzureCosmosDBConnection",
         "collectionName":"TransactedReturns"
      },
      {
         "type":"blob",
         "direction":"out",
         "name":"$return",
         "path":"nonpii/{filename}.json",
         "connection":"blobStorageAccount"
      }
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you say "override this behavior", I take it you want to circumvent the "exists" check, which ultimately is causing the 404 (as I see it), done by the `Blob` binding. While this would be possible, it would not really serve any real purpose. Is the *expected* 404 really that bad?

As to "why" it is happening, my guess is that it is happens while checking for existing container or other resources, needed for your specific `Blob`. It's hard to tell where it exactly happens, just from what we know, but the comment seen [in the WebJobs SDK](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/blob/c2621b65785137bd3cef7944f421f1182ef0daee/src/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage/Blobs/Config/BlobsExtensionConfigProvider.cs#L311-L332) specifically calls `ExistsAsync` to limit the expected 40x status codes. If one dives into the `Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob` repo where the `ExistsAsync` is implemented, you can see the `ExistsImpl` [expecting a 404 status code](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net/blob/b0d47bfd4c1c0dcbe60eaf373e2977cd7405aa5f/Lib/ClassLibraryCommon/Blob/CloudBlobContainer.cs#L2588-L2615) to determine whether the resource exists.

To circumvent the 404, you might be able to just use the [`BlobClient`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.blobs.blobclient?view=azure-dotnet) yourself, and just go straight ahead and create what you need created, without checking for existing resources. A fair warning though, this might ultimately cause far more issues than this expected 404 does (and tbh, the 404 is hardly causing any issues, as it is being handled by the SDK and storage lib).

Comment: Yes, I meant to avoid this "exists" check and overwrite if it already exists or at least does not in a "404" for this request when using Log Analytics to capture the logs

I agree with you when the blob is being written to the container, it is checking for existence, but I do not really care if the resource exists; I do not update it; I wanted to overwrite it blindly.

I can do custom implementation of Blob writes. But, there is no way I can capture the logs efficiently inside log analytics and have to implement custom telemetry to capture latencies for every request being made to service.